# export { default as x } does not infer type

Tags: typescript

Typescript does not infer the type of Activity when i export it from another file. I have activity defined as a constant, with inferred typing from mongoose:

**models.ts:**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const activitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})

export const Activity = mongoose.model("Activity", activitySchema);
```

This file sits in a folder with other (mongoose) related Typescript files. 
Another TS file that sits in the same folder, index.ts, exports this variable:

**index.ts:**

```
export { default as Activity } from "./models";
export { default as configureMongoose } from "./configureMongoose";
```

However, in index.ts, the type of `Activity` cannot be inferred. The type of the variable from the `"./configureMongoose"` reference however, is automatically inferred. This prevents me from being able to make use of the type related functions and properties.

How come the type is not automatically inferred?

Comment: There's no default export in `models.ts` so `default as Activity` does nothing.

Comment: Refactored it to be a default export. Thanks.