# How do I export default with type?

Tags: typescript

How can I rewrite this so that I don't have the `const`?

```
const theme: ITheme = { color: 'blue' };
export default theme;
```

The following will disable type checks which is not what I want.

```
export default  {color: Blue} as ITheme
```

May be related

- [export { default as x } does not infer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424757/export-default-as-x-does-not-infer-type) but diffent usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript type to object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66148283/typescript-type-to-object-literal)

Comment: Are you using  TS or TSX?,  if your not using TSX (IOW: React / JSX) 
 you can do ->  `export default <ITheme>{color: 'red'}`

Comment: I use both TS and TSX but your answer works well for TypeScript.  You can put that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For TypeScript 4.9+ you can use the `satisfies` keyword to ensure the type is statically checked:

```
export default { color: 'blue' } satisfies ITheme;
```

This will guarantee the type is valid, but may set a more specific type (`{ color: 'blue' }` instead of `ITheme`). If you need the more generic type, use `satisfies` *and* `as`:

```
export default { color: 'blue' } satisfies ITheme as ITheme;
```